# How to get the list of the pages i have liked on facebook using Graph API or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am scratching my head from a few days to get this thing done but i am not able to do it. developer.facebook says FQL is not available anymore and graph API do not provide any such thing.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

You need the "user_likes" permission, check out the docs for example code.

This will only return the Facebook Pages you like, it is NOT possible to get a list of all external links you like afaik.